# Get first element in array Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to add new 2 columns value services arr first and second value
but I'm getting the error:

> Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0;

```
production_target_datasource_df.withColumn("newcol",production_target_datasource_df["Services"].getItem(0))
```

```
    +------------------+--------------------+
    |         cid      |            Services|
    +------------------+--------------------+
    |845124826013182686|     [112931, serv1]|
    |845124826013182686|     [146936, serv1]|
    |845124826013182686|      [32718, serv2]|
    |845124826013182686|      [28839, serv2]|
    |845124826013182686|       [8710, serv2]|
    |845124826013182686|    [2093140, serv3]|
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the output of `production_target_datasource_df.printSchema()`.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Do you have any code to show ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use `.getItem(0)`

`production_target_datasource_df["Services"][0]` would be enough.

```
# Constructing your table:
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = sc.parallelize([Row(cid=1,Services=["2", "serv1"]),
Row(cid=1, Services=["3", "serv1"]),
Row(cid=1, Services=["4", "serv2"])]).toDF()
df.show()
+---+----------+
|cid|  Services|
+---+----------+
|  1|[2, serv1]|
|  1|[3, serv1]|
|  1|[4, serv2]|
+---+----------+

# Adding the two columns:
new_df = df.withColumn("first_element", df.Services[0])
new_df = new_df.withColumn("second_element", df.Services[1])
new_df.show()

+---+----------+-------------+--------------+
|cid|  Services|first_element|second_element|
+---+----------+-------------+--------------+
|  1|[2, serv1]|            2|         serv1|
|  1|[3, serv1]|            3|         serv1|
|  1|[4, serv2]|            4|         serv2|
+---+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: `AnalysisException: "Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0;"`

Answer (score 1):

As the error is saying, you need to pass a string not a 0.
Then, you wonder : what string should I pass ?

If you follow @pault advice, and printSchema, you will actually know what are the corresponding keys to your values in the list.

Here is the documentation of getItem, helping you figure this out. [image]

Another way to know what to pass, is to simply pass any string, you could type:

```
production_target_datasource_df.withColumn("newcol",production_target_datasource_df["Services"].getItem('0'))
```

and the logs will tell you what keys were expected.

Hope this helps ;)